# Libgdx enable proguard

Tags: libgdx, proguard

I have been wanting to enable proguard for a long time now, but it seems to much of a hassle.

But I was thinking if is posible to only enable proguard to remove classes that the program don't uses, I have a simple game weighting almost 25mb and I don't even have 2mb of assets, I don't care about obfuscation.

This should be easier to implement right? since most errors when enabling proguard are because of obfuscation?

Can I do this? how?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

**I use eclipse**

**`build.gradle` file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "test"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.5'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'

        admobVersion = '10.2.1';
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$admobVersion"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: proguard is mostly used for obfuscation but if you consider it for size, it only reduce 2-3 mb. How 25 mb with 2 mb of assets. I have 10 mb of .apk with 7.5 mb of assets.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I have no idea, Im guessing google play service lib add like 7mb and Im only using it for admob ads

Comment: I am also using ads sub module of google play service by `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1` but still 25 mb matters for libGDX project.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan  Okay so I double checked now, and when Im downloading the app from Google play, it says 5.96 mb, when installed in app info says 15.96mb, and Im 90% sure that I have seen it at 25mb, so that would be the data saving, BUT still is 15.96mb with 1.76mb of assets

Comment: @AbhishekAryan what do you mean by `sub module of google play service` I just threw the whole lib in there, sorry if I sound dumb, english is not my first language

Comment: `google play services` is a bundle of lot of different API, with different use like `fitness`, `wearable`, `analytics`, `drive` .....and many more. use only what you required instead of all,  you had to compile the entire package of APIs into your app.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan so do you think this is why my app weights so much?

Comment: not too much weight by this bundle but it's better to avoid unnecessary stuff in your .apk. In some cases, more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536 limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this inside android app module. App module having pre build `proguard-project.txt` file having proguard rules that apply on your libgdx projects.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true   
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
```

Uncommit this line inside project.properties file.

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Hopefully you're not using skin, some time skin creates problem because object fetched from .json.

Comment: I am using Skin, can you add how to add `sub module of google play service` instead of all the lib?

Comment: tell me what module you're using of google play services ?

Comment: How do I check this? where?

Comment: well I think proguard will eliminate all the unecessary classes of google play service right? so there's no point of adding only the module of google play services that I use

Comment: what are you using from google play service like may be you're using ads, google game services or some thing else

Comment: just for admob ads

Comment: instead of compiling all module by this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'` compile only ads module by this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'`

Comment: And it's better to use firebase instead of google-pay-services for AdMob Ad.

Comment: What are the advantages of using firebase?

Comment: Not necessary to migrate but with Firebase you have all in one place like admob , analytic , crash reporting , realtime database ,hosting , storage, authentication etc. otherwise no problems with google-services-ads

Comment: Hey im sorry to keep bothering you but, I added this `google_play_services_lib` like [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-(replaces-deprecated-AdMob))   a long time ago and I dont understand what you meant by saying replace `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'` with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'` since I did not did that to import the lib. I tried putting `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'` in gradle.build below dependecies, in project:android, and that did not work, could you explain this?

Comment: Please show your build.gradle file of android module. and Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: I Edited my question and added the build.gradle file, im using eclipse, after I edited the build.grade file, I also refresh gradle and clean all projects, my minSdk is 9  already, still doesnt work?

Comment: Your project is gradle based or you're manually imported in your Eclipse. What is inside your libs folder ?

Comment: Im pretty sure my project is gradle based, inside my libs folder was kryonet lib, seems I forgot to delete `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

Comment: you updated root build.gradle file, please update build.gradle of android module too ?

Comment: what should I write in `build.gradle` android? there's no dependencies block

Comment: create one there or you can use root build.gradle file, inside android section. write `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'`

Comment: my apology, ya you have then what's the problem ?

Comment: That classes like `AdView` cannot be resolve, as the lib is not in there

Comment: refresh your gradle dependencies and build again, it'll imported in your project. I have one more suggestion use Android Studio or IntellijIDEA. I also suffered when i was using eclipse.

Comment: That is was I was thinking, im downloading Android Studio to see if eclipse is the problem.